# How to use a variable as many images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

**Hello once again!**

Is it possible to use a variable as many images? I'll explain.

_medals are a ccsprite.
Instead of making like _medal1,_medal2 or _medal3. Maybe I can just use _medals to change my images.
I tried to code like this:

```
 if (_points >= 5){
 _medals.visible = TRUE;
 _medals = [CCSpriteframe framewithImage:@"diamondMedal"];
}
```

but that didn't work. Nothing pops up on the screen. I also use sprite builder to connect everything.

In spritebuilder I set the sprite frame to NULL on _medals.
Sorry if you don't understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content of a CCSprite by changing its CCTexture2D. This way a CCSprite that has already been instantiated can be reused

```
if(_points >= 5){
    CCTexture2D* newMedal = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"diamondMedal.png"];
    [_medals setTexture: newMedal];
}
```